# ffmpeg php convert in background

Tags: ffmpeg

Hier is the deal: I converted my file with next command:

```
$output = exec("ffmpeg -i ".$directory_path_full." -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 ".$directory_path.$file_name.".flv");
```

But now I need to tell database that processing is over! how to do that?
if converting is done, insert into database table videos row converted to 1.

also found this script:
$output = shell_exec('ffmpeg ' . escapeshellarg($directory_path_full) . ' ' . escapeshellarg($directory_path.$file_name.".flv"));

and again how to update database that completed?

Comment: it converts but I have no idea how to know when is done?

Answer (score 0):

`exec()` will not return until whatever you're executing completes, so basically:

```
exec("ffmpeg blah blah blah", $output, $return_var);

if ($return_val = "whatever value indicates success") {
    ... update database to indicate success ...
}
```

Don't assume the conversion succeeded and blindly update the database, always check if things actually succeeded.

Comment: I think with exec I'm running php file in background. Someone will upload movie and then leave that page. What I don't get it. If I just do if statment on $return_val does it gone a work in background? Please provide exacly codes, so I can understend better